# Improperly configured: Usage of the xml aspects requires lxml and defusedxml

Tags: python, xml, django, lxml

I'm trying to use XML for a Django website I'm making but I ran into the following error when I set the page to display xml:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /articles/api/article/

Usage of the XML aspects requires lxml and defusedxml.
```

The page was working the way I wanted it to when I set it to display json. And I thought I installed lxml and defusedxml when I used the command

```
pip install defusedxml "lxml>=3"
```

But I got this log on the command line. It was installing fine until some errors popped up:

```
Collecting defusedxml
  Using cached defusedxml-0.4.1.tar.gz
Collecting lxml>=3
  Using cached lxml-3.4.2.tar.gz
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
        Building lxml version 3.4.2.
        Building without Cython.
        Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Installing collected packages: lxml, defusedxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.2.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-HDr23E/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/deanna/django-deanna/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-HDr23E/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TMZGKJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/deanna/django-deanna/include/site/python2.7:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    Building lxml version 3.4.2.

    Building without Cython.

    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    running install

    running build

    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

   copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

   copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

   copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

 copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-HDr23E/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/deanna/django-deanna/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-HDr23E/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TMZGKJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/deanna/django-deanna/include/site/python2.7" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-HDr23E/lxml
```

I looked at similar posts about errors when installing lxml but these posts didn't have the same error messages as mine. I looked at the lxml documentation and tried to install it according to the documentation, but I still cannot get lxml or defusedxml installed.

I don't know what I'm installing incorrectly or what to do. But I appreciate any help that you can give me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz": that means you don't have zlib-dev or zlib1g-dev in installed depending on your linux distribution, try install first this library.

Comment: I fixed the problem but I used the command `apt-get install lib32z1-dev`. Thank you though.